# How do you get VS Code to write Debug stdout to the Debug Console?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am trying to debug my Python Pytest tests in VS Code, using the Testing Activity on the left bar. I am able to run my tests as expected, with some passing and some failing. I would like to debug the failing tests to more accurately determine what is causing the failures.

When I run an individual test in debug mode VS Code is properly hitting a breakpoint and stopping, and the Run and Debug pane shows the local variables. I can observe the status of local variables either in the Variables > Local pane or through the REPL, by typing the name of the variable.

When I try to print out any statement, such as using `> print("here")` I do not get any output to the Debug Console. When I reference a variable, or put the string directly using `> "here"` I do see the output to the Debug Console.

It seems to me that the stdout of my REPL is not displaying to the Debug Console. A number of answers online have been suggesting to add options like `"redirectOutput": true` or `"console": "integratedTerminal"`, but neither of those seem to have worked. My full `launch.json` is below:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "redirectOutput": true,
            "outputCapture": "std"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there another setting I'm missing to enable this output? Have I got the wrong console type?

Comment: hey! did you find a solution to this bug? I have the same problem, I already tried almost all configurations that I  found around, still not able to print, I can in my other mac, for some reason I the other one it's just not working

Comment: I did find one method on a StackOVerflow answer somewhere which pointed me in the right direction for my use case. I've put it as an answer down below, but it doesn't solve the underlying problem so I'm not going to accept it as an answer.

Comment: hey @WarSame maybe this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/678#issuecomment-1099559549) will help you, it solved my problem. last comment I post the solution, apparently was a problem with `pytest`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So After a lot of frustrating "debugging" I found a solution that worked for me (if you are using `pytest` as me):

#### tldr

Two solutions:

1. downgrade your vscode python extension to `v2022.2.1924087327` that will do the trick (or any version that had the `debugpy<=1.5.1`).
   [image]
2. Or, Launch the debbuger from the `debug tab` not the `testing tab`. And use a configuration like the following one

   ```
   {
       "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
       "type": "python",
       "request": "launch",
       "program": "${file}",
       "console": "integratedTerminal",
       "purpose": ["debug-test"], 
       "redirectOutput": true,
       "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}
   }
   ```
3. **Bonus**. If you are using `pytest` you can temporarily disable the [capture of the stdout of pytest](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function)  so your print statements, and the `print` function, *if you breakpoint inside the `contextmanager`, will work too. This is very cumbersome but points out the [original problem](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/899#issuecomment-1095384631) of why the prints are not longer working.

   ```
   def test_disabling_capturing(capsys):
       print('this output is captured')
       with capsys.disabled():
           print('output not captured, going directly to sys.stdout')
       print('this output is also captured')
   ```

##### the long explanation

so the problem apparently is that the `debugpy` (which is the library used by `vscode` python debugger) in is last version [`v1.6.0`](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/releases/tag/v1.6.0) fixed this ["bug (827)"](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/827). In a nutshell, this "bug" was that vscode "duplicated" all the stdout when debugging because it captures the `pytest` `stdout` and replicate it in the debugger console.
This is because, by default, `pytest` captures all the stdout and store it (so when running all test in parallel it doesn't create a mess).

After "fixing" this issue, now, when you launch the test via the `testing tab`, by default, `pytest` is capturing all the `stdout` and the "new" (`>=v1.6.1`) `debugpy` ignores it. Therefore, all the print statements are not shown anymore on the debug console, even when you call `print()` in a breakpoint, because are captured by pytest (IDK where the `pytest` captured stdout is showing/stored if it is anywhere). which, in my case is a PITA.

You can disable the `pytest` capture option using the flag `-s` or `--capture=no` when launching pytest in a console or even from the debug tab as a custom configuration. but the problem is that there is [no way (apparently)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053867/5318634) to add these parameters in vscode for the `testing tab` so pytest is executed using that option.

Therefore the solution that I found was to downgrade the python extension to a version that uses an older version of `debugpy` `v1.5.1`, you can see in the **python extension** changelog that from the  version [`2022.4.0`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#202240-30-march-2022) they update the `debugpy` version, so going before that did the trick for me, you will have the double `stdout` "bug" in the console, but the `print` statement will work.

ref: The [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/678#issuecomment-1099559549) that lead me to the solution

---

You may make your voice heard here in the vscode-python [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19322)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer Pablo! It's frustrating to not have the debug option available in the testing tab. For my purposes debugging the test directly is working fine, so I'll keep in mind to do that directly, rather than from within the testing tab. Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Thank you. After weeks of troubleshooting, thanks to your solution I finally can use debugging within vs code testing again.

Comment: I was able to add the `-s` argument to the testing tab. I've done that by creating a pytest.ini file in the root of my project. Then I added the `addopts = -s` under `[pytest]`

Comment: @ThiagoAlves Awesome, that worked! You should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

One possible workaround I saw online is to print the DF in Spark to a string, then paste it into Notepad++ and convert the \n values into newlines.

I was able to print the DF to a string using some code I found on another Stack Overflow answer:

```
def getShowString(df, n=20, truncate=True, vertical=False):
    if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
        return(df._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    else:
        return(df._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))
```

This can then be called using `getShowString(df)`

This does not solve the actual issue of getting terminal output directed to the debug window, but can help in this particular case.